# when try to "cordova requirements" get error "Cordova does not know requirements"

Tags: cordova

Following the Cordova tutorial "[Create your first Cordova app"](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/), Cordova successfully created the project and both ios and android platforms. Using Terminal command after cd to the project's folder

```
cordova requirements
```

fails with...

```
Cordova does not know requirements; try help for a list of all the available commands.
```

Cordova successfully created project and platforms for both ios and android. When type "help", "requirements" does not seem to be a command in the list. Uninstalling and re-installing + updating Cordova did not help. Was the command removed? Is something missing in the installation? How to get it to list requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, ensure that the current working directory is a Valid Cordova Project, `requirements` is a *Project Command*, meaning it can only be used when your working directory is a valid Cordova Project. This is from the Cordova command reference.

If your working directory is indeed a Valid Cordova Project, then there is something wrong with the installation. I would advise simply uninstalling and reinstalling cordova using **npm**

Comment: Cordova successfully created the project, and the command is being run from Terminal in the project folder. I tried deleting the project, "sudo npm uninstall -g cordova" and "sudo npm install -g cordova" and created the project again, adding the platforms, but the error persists.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere between Node and npm there is a problem that affects Cordova installation. This problem did not resolve without the following steps. Sorry the steps are not as clear as I would like but hope it will help someone.

1. sudo uninstall -g cordova
2. re-install Node using the MacOSX package installer on the Node site
3. update npm according to npm documentation
4. sudo install -g cordova
5. fix the "minimatch deprecated" error with `npm update -g minimatch@3.0.2`
6. now create a Cordova project
7. 'cordova add platform ios'
8. 'cordova add platform android'

Now,

```
cordova requirements
```

works.