# difficulty with Cordova - failure to add plugins (even core plugins)

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova

I'm following the official Apache Cordova tutorial to create an app in Cordova on Mac OSX.

For command

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-(anything)
```

Terminal throws error

```
Error: Failed to fetch package information for cordova-plugin-(anything)
```

For example, core plugins "cordova-plugin-device" AND "cordova-plugin-console" both fail with this error.

I've read several two-year-old SO questions that suggest it's a firewall issue, but I've downloaded npm, Cordova and a bunch of other things through Terminal. Is it really a firewall issue? If so, how to fix?

If it's not a firewall issue, why is Cordova failing to fetch and add the plugins, and what is the way to solve?

Here's the error output.

```
deborahs-MBP:hybrid-test deborah$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-device" via plugin registry
Error: Failed to fetch package information for cordova-plugin-device
    at     /Users/deborah/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/registry/registry.js:32:20
    at Request.cb [as _callback]     (/Users/deborah/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/registry/registry.js:251:9)
    at self.callback (/Users/deborah/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:95:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at ClientRequest.self.clientErrorHandler (/Users/deborah/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/request/index.js:257:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:306:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
```

Comment: @Deborah could be problem with the plugin Id you are using. Try simple plugin like cordova-plugin-device

Comment: cordova-plugin-device and cordova-plugin-console both fail with "Failed to fetch...".

Answer (score 1):

**Note**
I had a [second Cordova problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802429/when-try-to-cordova-requirements-get-error-cordova-does-not-know-requirements/38809138#38809138) posted that turned out to be related to the same issue. This process below resolved both issues.

---

**Somewhere between Node and npm there is a problem that affects Cordova installation.** This problem did not resolve without the following steps. Sorry the steps are not as clear as I would like but hope it will help someone.

1. sudo uninstall -g cordova
2. re-install Node using the MacOSX package installer on the Node site
3. update npm according to npm documentation
4. sudo install -g cordova
5. fix the "minimatch deprecated" error with `npm update -g minimatch@3.0.2`
6. now create a Cordova project
7. 'cordova add platform ios'
8. 'cordova add platform android'

Now,

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-*
```

works.